# UnitOfWork for different DbContext

Tags: c#, generics, unit-of-work

I have something like following

```
 //Following is the Constructor
    public UnitOfWork(IEmployeeContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    #endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._context.Dispose();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this._context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository
    {
        {
        return _employeeRepository??
            (_employeeRepository= new EmployeeRepository(_context));
    }

    }
```

Now the Problem is i have another repository which is not based on IEmployeeContext. Lets call that context IOfficeContext so it will be like

```
     get
        {
            return _officeRepository??
                (_officeRepository= new OfficeRepository(_context));
        }
```

The Context passed to OfficeRepository is IOfficeContext . Should i have two separate UnitOfWork for them? or some other clever thing can be done over here?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a common interface:

```
public interface IContext
{
    void Dispose();
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

And have both `IEmployeeContext` and `IOfficeContext` inherit from it. Then `UnitOfWork` could know only about `IContext` and will be able to handle both.

Comment: Chances are that they already both inherit from `DbContext` anyway.

Comment: Currently my IUnitOfWork has IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository  { get;} and IOfficeRepository OfficeRepository { get;} How that would be arranged then?

Comment: Is this another way to have a BaseUnitOfWork and then two separate UnitOfWorks for each context

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications, yeah, thinking of it a bit more, if these repositories are used only by corresponding contexts, then you should have a base UOW and its inheritors for each context. However if these repositories can be shared (possibly not now, but there is such a possibility), then you can have them both in your UOW.

Comment: They correspond to different databases and will never be shared. Not getting my head around how exactly generics will come to play here

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications, why would they? You are not required to use generics here indeed.

Comment: I meant not fully getting how BaseUnitOfWork would apply here